# C++ library with a Java-like API

Tags: java, c++, api

Hoping that anybody here knows about a good one: I'm looking for a (free to use) C++ library with a class hierarchy and methods resembling the Java API, with at least the I/O & networking part if it, specifically HTTP handling.

I work mainly with C & Java, but for this particular project C++ is recommended, so I thought of adopting a good set of C++ libraries without facing a steep learning curve.

Thanks in advance for any recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit)) is IMHO very java like.  I.e. they prefer [Java-Style Iterators](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq12-qt4-iterators.html) over the STL ones.  Qt includes networking ([examples](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/examples.html#network)) and much other stuff (like scripting via javascript)

Comment: QT. I'm tempted, but going GPL is out of question, that is, it will be rejected by management.

Comment: The troll tech link is dead

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries?

- Boost.[IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) provides a framework for defining streams, stream buffers and i/o filters.
- [Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) - Portable networking, including sockets, timers, hostname resolution and socket iostreams.
- Many [others](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0)....

The Boost libraries provide similar capabilities as compared to the Java API, but they very much 'look and feel' - appropriately - like a C++ library.

Comment: Thanks. I checked Boost:Asio, but it handles up to TCP, meaning that if I need to handle HTTP with sessions/cookies and stuff I will have to implement it myself. I wonder if is there any new proposal exclusively for HTTP in the works...

Comment: The cpp-netlib project - http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-netlib - is working on HTTP client support for inclusion in Boost.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the option of using something like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), which is slightly simpler than using something like Boost, while still being cross platform.

While the only time I used HTTP in Java was a long time ago, the interface for the POCO library looks fairly simple to use. It gives a example of basic FTP usage a something like this:

```
Poco::Net::FTPStreamFactory::registerFactory();
std::ofstream localFile(inputFile, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
Poco::URI uri(inputURL);
std::auto_ptr<std::istream> ptrFtpStream(Poco::Net::URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri));
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(*ptrFtpStream.get(), localFile);
```

Comment: I was checking it before, but I would like to have more feedback from the people here. Thanks.

Comment: @Rafael, Poco is a great library that builds upon the stl, follows all the C++ idioms, and yet appears to be Java-like. So I think it's a great choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ library that looked like a Java one would be a bad library, IMHO. The two languages are so very different that what is good design for one will almost inevitably be bad design for the other.

Comment: A C++ library that has the same interfaces as a java library wouldn't be a bad design imo. .NET was able to provide the same interfaces for quite a few very different languages and it's C++ libraries are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Mindroid](https://github.com/Himmele/Mindroid.cpp), which is primarily oriented to embeddded programming:

*Mindroid is an application framework (with focus on messaging and concurrency) that lets you create applications using a set of reusable components - just like Android. The name Mindroid has two different meanings. On one hand Mindroid is a minimal set of core Android classes and on the other hand these classes also form Android's mind (at least in my opinion).*